# How to Detect if a SKSpriteNode is in a SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, detection

I put a circular attack oval on a blue space ship and, if any `SKSpriteNode` enters the `SKShapeNode` (attack oval) the blue space ship can fire on the `SKSpriteNode`. The problem is that I can't figure out how to do the detection. I have tried physical bodies but, I can't have contact without having a collision.

Here is an example. I want the purple/blue attack circle to detect A,B,C,D,E

[image: I want the purple circle to detect A,B,C,D,E]

Here is the code I think you will need. RSSprite is short for red ship sprite

```
blueShip.position = CGPoint(x: 800, y: 400)

attackCircle = SKShapeNode(ellipseOfSize: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 400))
attackCircle.position = CGPoint(x: blueShip.position.x, y: blueShip.position.y)

RSSprite!.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 700)
RSSprite!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: RSSprite!.size)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the update method you can check for an [intersection of 2 nodes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/intersectsNode:) like this:

```
if([nodeA intersectsNode:nodeB]) {
    // you have a collision
}
```

Comment: I don't want to know when the `SKSpriteNode` hits the anchor point of the `SKShapeNode`. The red ship would basically collide with the blue ship before the `SKShapeNode` (attack oval) detected the `SKSpriteNode`. You got point E on the diagram above but not A,B,C,D. Also I think the code is suppose to be `nodeA.intersectsNode(nodeB)`

Comment: @Malcolm- If you add a node as a child you can use the intersectsNode to signal an intersect. Why are you using a shapeNode? You can just as well use a SKSpriteNode (clear color). The example I provided is in Obj-C.